# Cygwin `rsync` Local Folders Paths

Tags: windows, syntax, cygwin, mingw

I require to synchnorize two folders in a Cygwin or minGW installation between a folder in the current disk and a folder in another disk.

A call such as

`rsync -a dir1\ d:\dir2`

is illegal, because of the syntaxis of the path in Windows.

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname d: Name or service not known`

How should i write the paths in Cygwin for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Cygwin installed currently, but if I recall you're looking for something like:

```
rsync -a ./dir1 /cygdrive/c/dir2
```

Assuming that `dir1` is in your current working directory.  The problem with what you have provided is that cygwin doesn't know that `dir1` is a folder, it's trying to treat it as a hostname (e.g. you can use rsync between different machines with this syntax: `me@mycomputer:~/somefolder`).

To remove ambiguity, try:

```
rsync -a /cygdrive/d/path/to/dir1 /cygdrive/c/dir2
```

Where `c` and `d` are the drive letters for the particular drives you're looking for.